# Is there a way to open (arbitrary) core dumps with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, coredump

Looking for an alternative to command line gdb for examining core dumps on OSX - is there some way to get Xcode to open arbitrary core dumps w/ debugging symbols?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [MachOView](http://sourceforge.net/projects/machoview/)<sup>1</sup>?

It sounds like it might work for viewing core dumps *(aside from everything else it can do.)*

<sup>1</sup> Found from [this reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O).

Comment: I am going to extend MachOView to support core dumps
Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: An important part of viewing a core file is being able to look at stack traces of different threads, examine variable values and so on.  MachOView seems to be a binary viewer, which is probably useful for some things, but for understanding why a program crashed, not so much.